# RuntimeError: python multiprocessing error

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I am trying to use parallel processing in python using the following code:

```
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import FarimaModule
from  statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mp

# Here I define some variables: p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs, listFile

def implement(fname,p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs):
    # It is a really long code

# run the function 'implement' in parallel for different values of the input variable 'fname'
pool = mp.Pool(10)
results = [pool.apply(implement, args=(fname,p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs)) for fname in listFile]
pool.close()
```

But it throws the following error:

```
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Others have posted questions with the same error. But I am not able to implement solutions posted there as it is unclear how do I adapt those solutions for my code.

Comment: Did you add `if __name__ == '__main__':` as the error message indicates? The [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) explains the need for that line.

Comment: More specifically, the last three lines need to be executed only in the main thread.  The way you have it, each newly started thread will read your file and start yet another pool of ten threads.  The pool creation code needs to only be executed once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could not find `mp.Pool.apply()` method illustrated there. But the `pool.map()`  seems to be working.

Comment: @FrankYellin I was adding the `if __name__ == '__main__':' after `pool = mp.Pool`. That is why it was not working. It works if I add `if __name__ == '__main__':' before this line. But now it seems that it is not running in sequence like a usual for loop; it is not parallelizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some systems, multiprocessing has to spawn a new copy of python and import your module to get to the worker code. Anything at module level is executed again... including the parent code that creates the pool. This would be an infinite recursion except python detects the problem and gives you a handy tip. You would follow it by

```
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import FarimaModule
from  statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mp

# Here I define some variables: p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs, listFile

def implement(fname,p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs):
    # It is a really long code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run the function 'implement' in parallel for different values of the input variable 'fname'
    pool = mp.Pool(10)
    results = [pool.apply(implement, args= 
       (fname,p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs)) for fname in listFile]
    pool.close()
```

A top level python script always has the name `"__main__"`. When imported by the subprocess, its now a module and has a different name.

[pool.apply](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) is likely not the method you want - it waits for the pool worker to complete. `map` may be the better choice. I chunks (groups) input. In your case, with an expensive calculation, you likely want a small chunksize. `starmap` is just `map` with multiple parameters.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run the function 'implement' in parallel for different values of the input variable 'fname'
    with mp.Pool(10) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(implement, 
            [(fname,p_max,q_max,m_list,wlen,mstep,fs)) 
                for fname in listFile],
            chunksize=1)
```

Comment: This code is working, but it is not doing parallel processing. It is iterating over 'fname` sequentially.

Comment: That's `apply`. You could `apply_async` or use `map` like the example I added.

Comment: `pool.apply` uses one thread.  If you want to use multiple threads, you must either make multiple calls to `pool.apply` or use one of the varieties of `pool.map()`.

Comment: Thanks all. pool.starmap is working for me.